# Get list of values from several paths in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lodash

I have an object with several nested layers of arrays and subobjects, from which I need to extract the values from some paths. Is there some library or native function which can help me do that? I'm already using Lodash and jQuery, but have a hard time figuring out how to simplify this problem.

Example:

```
{
  a: [
    {
      b: 0,
      c: 1
    },
    {
      b: 1,
      c: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to get a list of all `a[0..n].b`.

My actual object is much larger and has 3 layers of arrays and a path like `syn[0].sem[0].pdtb3_relation[0].sense`, so I'd rather not write 3 nested `for` loops if a library function exists.

Comment: Have a look at lodash's [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach()` to iterate through array.

```js
var o = {
  a: [
    {
      b: 0,
      c: 1
    },
    {
      b: 1,
      c: 2
    }
  ]
}

Object.keys(o).forEach(a => o[a].forEach(y => console.log(y.b)));
```

Comment: I seriously wonder why there isn't a jQuery-like library for paths in JSON objects, with an XPath-like syntax. -.- But thanks, this is also helpful.

Comment: Glad to help you :)